# Why a Kivy Button may not propagate events?

Tags: python, kivy

I have the following code in a kivy app. I am pasting only the code related to Button as this is what is  not working. The rest of the code is about displaying the list data in a datagrid, which works fine.

```
class PnLScreen(Screen):
    data = ListProperty(defaultvalue=[])
    processing = BooleanProperty(defaultvalue=False)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        tryout.get_nse_prices()
        tryout.get_bse_prices()
        tryout.get_isin_to_symbol_map()
        self.box = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        button = Button(size_hint_y=None)
        button.bind(on_press=self.go_home)
        self.box.add_widget(button)

    def go_home(self,instance):
        print("called from %s" % instance.text)
        # will figure out how to go home!
```

Now the button is displayed when the screen becomes current. But on clicking on the button, the bound function go_home is never called. I use buttons in other screens where it works. So I am not sure why this will not! Actually I am quite exasperated not being able to get this simple thing working.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You added the button to the boxlayout at `self.box.add_widget(button)`, but you didn't add the boxLayout to PnLScreen. (`self.add_widget(self.box)`). Which means both the button and the boxlayout will never be displayed. So the button you clicked was different from the one you created in the code above.

Comment: Thanks. I did that , that is , self.add_widget(self.box). The button is displayed, but the press event is simply not generated( or propagated). Not sure how to debug this. This works for buttons on the main screen( i have two screens).

Comment: Then I have no idea. If you post a runnable example that re-produce the issue, I might be able to find the cause of the issue.

Comment: https://github.com/tksundar/mark2market/blob/master/PandLScreen.py

Comment: Sorry I don't wanna debug your entire application. I'd suggest using the inspector to figure out which button you pressed. https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.modules.html